# 2d Object (drawing) wont move

Tags: transforms, keyframes, layers, 2d, object-mode

I'm trying to adjust my drawings position in Object mode but every time i move onto the next frame, it snaps back in place. I've check my other layers to see if the problem was with all of blender but some of my other objects work but others dont move either. Im stuck and cant carry on with animating :/

Comment: Do you actually save the keyframe before jumping to the next frame ?

Comment: how to you do that, i assumed each framed saved itself. Thats how ive been doing it

Comment: Well it saves itself automatically only when you press the circle icon on the left of the play/pause icons on top of the timeline. But if this is not activated, you have to manually set the keyframes. You can either right click in the field you want to save > Create (or Insert) keyframes OR you can simply hover your mouse over said field and press `I` on your keyboard

Comment: Thanks it started working again when i enabled the circle thing. I probably turned it off when i was having another problem with blender accidentally. Thank you so much!